# Best way to make a function that imports, parses, and then filters a JSON String for a specific item/key?

Tags: json, vba

I would like to make a function that takes a stock's ticker and retrieves historical financial statement data from it.

I can successfully import a string with a Get HttpRequest - with the string being:

{"2021-12-31":{"date":"2021-12-31","filing_date":"2022-02-18","currency_symbol":"USD","researchDevelopment":null,"effectOfAccountingCharges":null,"incomeBeforeTax":"133731000.00","minorityInterest":"0.00","netIncome":"135443000.00","sellingGeneralAdministrative":"240256000.00","sellingAndMarketingExpenses":"333453000.00","grossProfit":null,"reconciledDepreciation":"7541000.00","ebit":"137005000.00","ebitda":"144546000.00","depreciationAndAmortization":"7541000.00","nonOperatingIncomeNetOther":null,"operatingIncome":null,"otherOperatingExpenses":null,"interestExpense":"3274000.00","taxProvision":"-1712000.00","interestIncome":"50588000.00","netInterestIncome":"47314000.00","extraordinaryItems":null,"nonRecurring":null,"otherItems":null,"incomeTaxExpense":"-1712000.00","totalRevenue":"841439000.00","totalOperatingExpenses":null,"costOfRevenue":null,"totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet":"-7150000.00","discontinuedOperations":null,"netIncomeFromContinuingOps":"135443000.00","netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares":"135443000.00","preferredStockAndOtherAdjustments":null},"2020-12-31":{"date":"2020-12-31","filing_date":"2021-03-18","currency_symbol":"USD","researchDevelopment":null,"effectOfAccountingCharges":null,"incomeBeforeTax":"5950000.00","minorityInterest":"404000.00","netIncome":"5983000.00","sellingGeneralAdministrative":"83190000.00","sellingAndMarketingExpenses":"99659000.00","grossProfit":null,"reconciledDepreciation":"2278000.00","ebit":"14380000.00","ebitda":"16658000.00","depreciationAndAmortization":"2278000.00","nonOperatingIncomeNetOther":null,"operatingIncome":null,"otherOperatingExpenses":null,"interestExpense":"8026000.00","taxProvision":"371000.00","interestIncome":"12842000.00","netInterestIncome":"4816000.00","extraordinaryItems":null,"nonRecurring":null,"otherItems":null,"incomeTaxExpense":"371000.00","totalRevenue":"227601000.00","totalOperatingExpenses":null,"costOfRevenue":null,"totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet":null,"discontinuedOperations":null,"netIncomeFromContinuingOps":"5579000.00","netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares":"135443000.00","preferredStockAndOtherAdjustments":null},"2019-12-31":{"date":"2019-12-31","filing_date":"2019-12-31","currency_symbol":"USD","researchDevelopment":null,"effectOfAccountingCharges":null,"incomeBeforeTax":"-4946000.00","minorityInterest":"1026000.00","netIncome":"-466000.00","sellingGeneralAdministrative":"56812000.00","sellingAndMarketingExpenses":"93175000.00","grossProfit":null,"reconciledDepreciation":"774000.00","ebit":"26093000.00","ebitda":"26867000.00","depreciationAndAmortization":"774000.00","nonOperatingIncomeNetOther":null,"operatingIncome":null,"otherOperatingExpenses":null,"interestExpense":"26485000.00","taxProvision":"74000.00","interestIncome":"30827000.00","netInterestIncome":"4342000.00","extraordinaryItems":null,"nonRecurring":null,"otherItems":null,"incomeTaxExpense":"74000.00","totalRevenue":"163818000.00","totalOperatingExpenses":null,"costOfRevenue":null,"totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet":null,"discontinuedOperations":null,"netIncomeFromContinuingOps":"-5020000.00","netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares":"-466000.00","preferredStockAndOtherAdjustments":null},"2018-12-31":{"date":"2018-12-31","filing_date":"2018-12-31","currency_symbol":"USD","researchDevelopment":null,"effectOfAccountingCharges":null,"incomeBeforeTax":"-11218000.00","minorityInterest":"12001000.00","netIncome":"-12319000.00","sellingGeneralAdministrative":"35236000.00","sellingAndMarketingExpenses":"63633000.00","grossProfit":null,"reconciledDepreciation":"314000.00","ebit":"14164000.00","ebitda":"14478000.00","depreciationAndAmortization":"314000.00","nonOperatingIncomeNetOther":null,"operatingIncome":null,"otherOperatingExpenses":null,"interestExpense":"26483000.00","taxProvision":"0.00","interestIncome":"37314000.00","netInterestIncome":"10831000.00","extraordinaryItems":null,"nonRecurring":null,"otherItems":null,"incomeTaxExpense":null,"totalRevenue":"96066000.00","totalOperatingExpenses":null,"costOfRevenue":null,"totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet":null,"discontinuedOperations":null,"netIncomeFromContinuingOps":"-11218000.00","netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares":"-12319000.00","preferredStockAndOtherAdjustments":null},"2017-12-31":{"date":"2017-12-31","filing_date":"2017-12-31","currency_symbol":"USD","researchDevelopment":null,"effectOfAccountingCharges":null,"incomeBeforeTax":"-8855000.00","minorityInterest":"12001000.00","netIncome":"-7717000.00","sellingGeneralAdministrative":"25663000.00","sellingAndMarketingExpenses":"33838000.00","grossProfit":null,"reconciledDepreciation":"93000.00","ebit":"1709000.00","ebitda":"1802000.00","depreciationAndAmortization":"93000.00","nonOperatingIncomeNetOther":null,"operatingIncome":null,"otherOperatingExpenses":null,"interestExpense":"9420000.00","taxProvision":"6000.00","interestIncome":"15548000.00","netInterestIncome":"6128000.00","extraordinaryItems":null,"nonRecurring":null,"otherItems":null,"incomeTaxExpense":"6000.00","totalRevenue":"55970000.00","totalOperatingExpenses":null,"costOfRevenue":null,"totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet":null,"discontinuedOperations":null,"netIncomeFromContinuingOps":"-8861000.00","netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares":"-7717000.00","preferredStockAndOtherAdjustments":null}}

But am having issues pulling beyond one year's worth of data using this approach:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-api-how-to-return-more-than-32767-characters.1166944/

Unfortunately, I do not know how to use it to output an array of values as opposed to just one line.

Ideally, I would love to be able to pull multiple years' data for "totalRevenue". I use TimHall's VBA-JSON currently.

What I would currently like is a variant of the function that enables multiple lines without the need for knowing the ("date") part of the function.

I have seen dictionary approaches, filter string approaches, but am having difficulties tying both of each back into the formula. I am largely looking for an approach that does not make me have to rename the dates - and that could instead use a fill to where the only customizable field will be the metric (e.g., totalRevenue, ebit...).

Any help would be phenomenal.

[It would ideally come out like this with the use of a function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8xYi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The custom function (add a parameter to pass in a metric and amend the code accordingly, and change the name of the function as desired) . . .

```
Public Function GetStockResults() As Variant

    'your code here
    '
    '
    '
    '
    
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(httpRequest.ResponseText)
    
    ReDim arr(0 To json.Count - 1, 0 To 1)
    
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    i = 0
    For Each k In json.Keys
        'Debug.Print "totalRevenue", json(k)("totalRevenue")
        arr(i, 0) = "totalRevenue"
        arr(i, 1) = json(k)("totalRevenue")
        i = i + 1
    Next k
    
    GetStockResults = arr()
    
End Function
```

Your worksheet formula . . .

```
=GetStockResults()
```

Comment: Right, thank you for the briefness. It works excellently. Would you happen to know of a way to transport the results from the Immediate Window into cells? Preferably as the same location of the cell which I use the function?

Comment: Do you mean that you want this code in a user defined function so that you can use a worksheet formula to return the results?  Or are you going to have this code in a procedure so that it writes the results in your worksheet?  Also, which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I would like to put it in a User defined Function. I am using the latest function of Excel.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support dynamic arrays?

Comment: Yes, I can use the filter, unique, sortby, sort functions.

Comment: See my edited post.

Comment: Thank you, this is amazing. I greatly appreciate it. This will save me tons of time. For my future reference, do you have any VBA guides/sources you would like to recommend?

Comment: That's great, I'm glad I could help.  As far as recommendations, StackOverflow and other Excel/VBA forums are a great place to learn.  Also, I would recommend reading a good book, such as Microsoft Office Excel 20XX Power Programming with VBA (which ever one is their latest).